# External SD card changes mount point

Tags: external-sd, storage, mount

I have a Moto e5 Plus (Android 8.0.0) that has a 128GB Samsung Evo card in it. The card works well in the device (freshly formatted), but has an odd system of mounting.

On previous devices, the external card was mounted on `/storage/ext_sdcard` or some similar place that was always constant. On the Plus, the mount point for the external card is `/storage/32313943-2d33-3032-4600-d8b34000d8b3`, which is great. For now. Until it reboots. Then the UUID for the card changes, and any media referenced with the old mount point is now inaccessible. I realize one way around it is to make your app just look for what UUID is available and use that, but my question is in reference to a third-party app so I don't have modification abilities.

I really don't care what the mount point is, but is there a way to stop it from changing every time the card is remounted or the phone is rebooted?